# Sort XML by name,attribute name,attribute value,element value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to **`Sort XML`** by **`element Name`** then by **`Attribute Name`** & **`Attribute value`** then by **`element value`** and save the results again in XML file with comments, whitespaces.

I achieved this upto element name and element's value by using `LINQ` but now i'm facing a problem in sorting with attribute name and its value.

```
    private void SortnSave(string filePath, string savePath)
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        var result = Sort(xDoc.Root);
        result.Save(savePath);
    }

    private XElement Sort(XElement element)
    {
        var xe = new XElement(element.Name, element.Elements().OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToString(), new SplitComparer())
            .ThenBy(x => x.Value.ToString(), new SplitComparer()).Select(x => Sort(x)));

        if (!xe.HasElements)
        {
            xe.Value = element.Value;
        }

        if (element.HasAttributes)
        {
            foreach (XAttribute item in element.Attributes().OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToString()).ThenBy(x => x.Value.ToString()))
            {
                xe.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return xe;
    }

    public class SplitComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            var partsOfX = x.Split('.');

            int firstNumber;
            if (partsOfX.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(partsOfX[1], out firstNumber))
            {
                var secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(y.Split('.')[1]);

                return firstNumber.CompareTo(secondNumber);
            }

            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
```

How can I add **attribute name and attribute value sorting criteria** inside below linq query in between element name and element value sorting criteria?

```
var xe = new XElement(element.Name, element.Elements().OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToString(), new SplitComparer())
            .ThenBy(x => x.Value.ToString(), new SplitComparer()).Select(x => Sort(x)));
```

Sample XML :

```
<Coordinates>
<Coordinate Name="P" Value="C">
<Y>0</Y>
<X>0</X>    
</Coordinate>
<Coordinate Name="Q" Value="D">
    <X>50</X>
    <Y>25</Y>
</Coordinate>
<Coordinate Value="D" Name="Z" >
    <X>100</X>
    <Y>100</Y>
</Coordinate>
</Coordinates>
```

Result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coordinates>
<Coordinate Name="P" Value="C">
<X>0</X>
<Y>0</Y>
</Coordinate>
<Coordinate Name="Z" Value="D">
<X>100</X>
<Y>100</Y>
</Coordinate>
<Coordinate Name="Q" Value="D">
<X>50</X>
<Y>25</Y>
</Coordinate>
</Coordinates>
```

Expected Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coordinates>
<Coordinate Name="P" Value="C">
<X>0</X>
<Y>0</Y>
</Coordinate>
<Coordinate Name="Q" Value="D">
<X>50</X>
<Y>25</Y>
</Coordinate>
<Coordinate Name="Z" Value="D">
<X>100</X>
<Y>100</Y>
</Coordinate>
</Coordinates>
```

**UPDATE :**

I achieved this by creating string of all sorted attributes and comparing it in linq query.

```
  var xe = new XElement(element.Name, element.Elements().OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToString(), new SplitComparer()).ThenBy(x => GetAttributeWithValueString(x))
            .ThenBy(x => x.Value.ToString(), new SplitComparer()).Select(x => Sort(x)));

    private string GetAttributeWithValueString(XElement element)
    {
        string attrStr = string.Empty;

        if (element.HasAttributes)
        {
            foreach (XAttribute item in element.Attributes().OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToString()).ThenBy(x => x.Value.ToString()))
            {
                attrStr += item.ToString() + " ";
            }
        }

        return attrStr;
    }
```

But is it a good way?.. Can anyone suggest me better way than this??

Comment: Could you please post the XML.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi .. posted sample, result and expected result..

Comment: I would think something like this would work :         var xe = element.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => y.Elements()).OrderBy(z => z.Attributes.Name);

Comment: @jdweng.. But i want to sort with attribute name and its value both in one predicate...

Comment: I can't test but try something like this : var xe2 = xe1.Element(“Coordinates”).OrderBy(x => new object[] {x.Element(“Coordinate”).Attribute(“Name”).Value, xElement(“Coordinate”).Attribute(“Value”).Value, (int)x.Element(“X”), (int)x.Element(“Y”)});